# plotting linear time trend using facet

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I would like to overlay a linear trend regression model over data points using `facet wrap`:

The linear regression I am looking for is

`value ~ time`  where time is the `seq(1:length(dates))`

In the example below group A has 3 observation and group B has 4 observations

My code is

```
dates = as.Date(c("2017-01-01", "2017-02-01", "2017-03-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-02-01", 
    "2017-03-01", "2017-04-01"))
group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B")
value = c(2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 5)
data = data.frame(dates = dates, group = group, value = value)


ggplot(data = data, aes(x = factor(dates), y = value, group = 1)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = value ~ seq(1:length(dates))) + 
    facet_wrap(~group, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y")
```

I would also like to print the slope coefficient of the regression on the charts

any idea?

Comment: `formula` is specified in terms of the aesthetics, i.e. `x` and `y`. In this case, though, you can just get rid of it and go with `geom_smooth(method = 'lm')`. Printing the slope is rather more work, as it's not a quantity made available through `stat_smooth`. It's probably easier to do your modeling first, assemble your data, and then plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little bit of tidyverse magic, you can keep your models in your data.frame, which lets you plot whatever you'd like:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>% nest(-group) %>% 
    mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(value ~ dates, data = .x)), 
           predictions = map(model, predict), 
           slope = map_dbl(model, ~coef(.x)[2])) %>% 
    unnest(data, predictions) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(dates, value)) + 
    geom_line(color = 'gray50') + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_line(aes(y = predictions), color = 'blue', size = .75) + 
    geom_text(aes(label = paste('beta==', round(slope, 5)), 
                  x = min(dates) + 1, 
                  y = max(value)), 
              hjust = 0, parse = TRUE) + 
    facet_wrap(~group, ncol = 1, scales = 'free_y')
```

[image]

If you'd rather, you could graph confidence intervals by hand, too, or just use `geom_smooth` as usual:

```r
data %>% nest(-group) %>% 
    mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(value ~ dates, data = .x)), 
           slope = map_dbl(model, ~coef(.x)[2])) %>% 
    unnest(data) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(dates, value)) + 
    geom_line(color = 'gray50') + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(method = 'lm') +
    geom_text(aes(label = paste('beta==', round(slope, 5)), 
                  x = min(dates) + 1, 
                  y = max(value)), 
              hjust = 0, parse = TRUE) + 
    facet_wrap(~group, ncol = 1, scales = 'free_y')
```

[image]

Note this approach is more computationally intense, as `geom_smooth` refits the models. If you like, broom and modelr can be useful for munging models, too.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
data$id <- ave(data$value, data$group, FUN=seq_along)

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = factor(dates), y = value, group = group)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(x=id, y=value)) + 
  facet_wrap(~group, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]